# How to keep all comments in new latex file made by newwrite command?

Tags: macros

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}

\begin{document}

\newwrite\copyfile
\immediate\openout\copyfile=Theorem.tex 
\immediate\write\copyfile{hello %this is comment 1
                                %this is comment 2
                            }
\immediate\closeout\copyfile                        
\end{document}
```

Above code make `Theorem.tex` file. But all comments (this is comment 1, this is comment 2) disapper. How to keep all comments `%this is comment 1, %this is comment 2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}

\begin{document}

\newwrite\copyfile
\immediate\openout\copyfile=Theorem.tex 
{\catcode`\%=12
\immediate\write\copyfile{hello %this is comment 1
                                %this is comment 2
                            }
}
\immediate\closeout\copyfile                        
\end{document}
```

making `%` have catcode 12 will lose its comment status (you may also want to preserve newlines?)

The above makes

```
hello %this is comment 1 %this is comment 2
```

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}

\begin{document}

\newwrite\copyfile
\immediate\openout\copyfile=Theorem.tex 
{\catcode`\%=12
\endlinechar=`\^^J%
\immediate\write\copyfile{hello %this is comment 1
                                %this is comment 2
                            }%
}%
\immediate\closeout\copyfile                        
\end{document}
```

produces

```
hello %this is comment 1
%this is comment 2
```

Comment: Thank you. But it doesn't work in this case, can you help me one more time: ```\usepackage{environ} \newtheorem{question}{exercise}
\RenewEnviron{question}{
 \BODY% Print question
 \immediate\write\copyfile{\string\begin{question}}
  {\catcode`\%=12
   \endlinechar=`\^^J%
   \immediate\write\copyfile{\unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}} }
  \immediate\write\copyfile{\string\end{question}}
}``` : every comment in BODY will disapper when new file is made.

Comment: like any verbatim command you can't normally include it in the definition of another command. The comments have already been read as comments before `\BODY` is defined so before the catcocde changes take effect

Answer (score 0):

A more complicated example that allows all special characters. This works with Plain LuaTeX and LuaLaTeX, with some changes it will also work with other engines. The implementation is similar to the `filecontents` environment of the LaTeX kernel.

```
\catcode`@=11

\newwrite\file
\immediate\openout\file=xxx.zzz\relax

\newif\if@firstline

\def\@makeother#1{\catcode`#112\relax}

\begingroup
\obeylines%
\gdef\verbatimwrite#1#2{%
    \begingroup%
    \let\do\@makeother \dospecials%
    \expandafter\edef\expandafter\E\expandafter{%
        \expandafter\csstring\expandafter\\\expandafter%
        \scantextokens\expandafter{\csstring#2}}%
    \edef\reserved@b{\def\noexpand\reserved@b####1\E####2\E####3\relax}%
    \reserved@b{%
        \ifx\relax##3\relax%
          \if@firstline%
            \wlog{Wrong input `##1' discarded.}%
            \@firstlinefalse%
          \else\immediate\write#1{##1}%
          \fi%
        \else%
          \let^^M\endgroup%
          \if@firstline%
          \errhelp{The verbatim writing command must not end on the same line.}%
          \errmessage{Writing nothing}%
          \else%
          \ifx\relax##1\relax%
          \else%
          \wlog{Writing text `##1' before%
              \E\space as last line.}%
          \immediate\write#1{##1}%
          \fi%
          \ifx\relax##2\relax%
          \else%
          \wlog{Ignoring text `##2' after \E.}%
          \fi%
          \fi%
        \fi%
        ^^M}%
    \@firstlinetrue%
    \obeylines%
    \edef^^M##1^^M{\noexpand\reserved@b##1\E\E\relax}%
    ^^M}%
\endgroup

Let's test:

\verbatimwrite\file\endverbatimwrite This is deleted!
%1234 \undefined¼ #$ h^∬∮
%\\ ∑≋ ä≝ß‡ ~ ²³^
}}}{\relax≈Ðű

&&
%6‡k%eŁŴ
%₉kϒ∭×‱¾ \endverbatimwrite This is deleted, too!

\def\WRITE{\verbatimwrite\file\}

\WRITE This ist deleted!
][}]Ψ♠♣
\ This is deleted, too!

\immediate\closeout\file
\bye
```

The command `\verbatimwrite` takes 2 arguments. `#1` is the write stream, `#2`
ends the writing.

The gererated file contains:

```
%1234 \undefined¼ #$ h^∬∮
%\\ ∑≋ ä≝ß‡ ~ ²³^
}}}{\relax≈Ðű

&&
%6‡k%eŁŴ
%₉kϒ∭×‱¾ 
][}]Ψ♠♣
```